# Is there a name for the complete graph on $n$ vertices raised to the $k$ under cartesian product.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, reference-request, terminology

Is there a name for the graph $G_{n,k} = \underbrace{K_n \square \dots K_n }_{\text{k times}}$ ?

Explicitly it is the graph with vertex set $[n]^k$ and edges between tuples that differ in exactly one coordinate.

I know that when $n=2$ this graph is called the hypercube of dimension $k$.

I think this sort of graph comes up with dealing with things like multiple choice exams so it may be the subject of some study.

I have tried looking for it but have not obtained any results thus far.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [Hamming graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_graph) $H(k,n)$. It has this name because adjacent vertices are precisely the elements of $[n]^k$ at Hamming distance $1$ from each other.

When $k=2$ it is called the [rook graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rook%27s_graph).

Just referring to it by notation, as $K_n^{\square k}$, is also reasonably concise.

Comment: Thank you very much.